# Problema al rescatar datos en Google Sheet usando RegexExtract

Tags: regex, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo una base de datos en Google Spreadsheet en que hay celdas que tienen más de una dirección de e-mail. Estoy ocupando la función `RegexExtract`, pero solo me extrae la primera dirección del e-mail que encuentra.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que haga un loop o logre rescatar todos los e-mails que están en la misma celda?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La celda `E2` contiene 3 direcciones e-mail. La celda `F2` tiene función `=Regexextract(E2;"[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}")` que extrae solo el primer e-mail.

¿Cómo logro que haga loop hasta el último e-mail (podrían ser más de 3)?

Comment: Esta pregunta es un publicación cruzada. Publicado también en https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs-es/vgnWpwFT5g4/iHxJ7sKPCAAJ. En mi opinión no está mal en que se haga, pero debería mencionarse. Cabe mencionar que un problema que se presenta al publicar de forma cruzada es que se podrían recibir las mismas respuestas en los distintos lugares pero si estas no fueran satisfactorias, el "deber ser" sería actualizar y/o hacer las aclaraciones pertinente en los lugares en los que se realizaron las publicaciones.

Comment: Según se puede ver en el hilo referido en mi comentario previo, el ejemplo mostrado en la imagen no corresponde al caso de uso ya que las direcciones de correo no se encuentran en líneas una por línea sino que se encuentran como parte de un bloque de texto que incluye nombres de usuario de twitter. Lo apropiado es que actualices la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Para esta solución sería mucho mejor y, sobre todo más legible, armar un script. Sin embargo, sólo por divertirme un rato, les doy dos soluciones:

---

### Opción 1: fácil, con [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Eliminando todo **lo que no sea** un email. Para eso:

1. Coincidir con el texto que está antes del email
2. Coincidir con el email (y capturarlo)
3. Reemplazar todo lo anterior (1 y 2) con el valor capturado en 1.
4. Además agregarle un `;` para separar los emails, sino no se diferenciaría uno de otro.

**Solución**

```
=REGEXREPLACE(E2;"[^A-z0-9._%+-]*(?:[A-z0-9._%+-][^A-z0-9._%+-]*)*?([A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4})";"$1;")
```

**Descripción**

```
#TEXTO ANTES DEL EMAIL
[^A-z0-9._%+-]*              # Consumir los caracteres que no pueden estar al principio del mail
(?:                          # REPETIR 0+, la menor cant. de veces
    [A-z0-9._%+-]            #   Caracteres que pueden estar, pero no son el mail
    [^A-z0-9._%+-]*          #   Caracteres que no pueden estar al principio del mail
)*?                          # FIN REPETIR

#EL EMAIL
([A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4})  # Entre paréntesis lo captura en $1
```

Y lo reemplazamos con `"$1;"`. O sea el email y un punto y coma para separarlos.

---

### Opción 2: con [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) y *magia* en la expresión regular

¿Y si quisiéramos obtener 1 solo email de los que están en el texto? ¿Si nos interesa elegir el primero, el segundo, alguno en particular?

Bueno, se puede hacer perfectamente, pero desde ya les anticipo, no va a ser nada fácil de entender, y sobre todo, una pesadilla a la hora de mantenerlo. Así que consideren que es algo divertido de ver, pero no lo usen si en algún momento pueden llegar a querer modificarlo.

Usamos una columna para poner qué número de email queremos, y en la siguiente obtenemos ese email:

[image: Estructura de la planilla]

**Solución**

```
=RegexExtract(B2;"(?:[A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}(?:[^A-z0-9._%+-][A-z0-9._%+-]*)*?[^A-z0-9._%+-]+){" & C2 - 1 & "}([A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4})")
```

**Descripcion**

Usando la misma lógica que antes, se consume el texto entre emails, pero esta vez se requiere que se repita `N` veces (el valor de la celda) antes de coincidir con el mail. Y capturamos el último mail (que es el valor devuelto por la función).

```
(?:                                          # REPETIR
    [A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4}   #   Coincidir con email
    (?:[^A-z0-9._%+-][A-z0-9._%+-]*)*?       #   Texto que no es
    [^A-z0-9._%+-]+                          #   Tiene que separar 2 mails
){⋘n⋙}                                     # FIN REPETIR n veces 
                                             # (⋘n⋙ se cambia por la celda)
([A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4})     # Capturar email
```

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si utilizas la función `REGEXREPLACE`, para buscar iterativamente todas las coincidencias de acuerdo a tu validación, para luego remplazar cada línea por la coincidencia del primer parentesis.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(E2;"^([A-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-z0-9.-]+\.[A-z]{2,4})";"$1")
```

**Explicación**:

`^`: Inicio de línea

`()`: Primera captura

`$1`: Remplaza por primera captura

Comment: Está anclado al principio de la línea y no reemplazaría el texto. De esta forma no funciona para los ejemplos publicados en el link